Effect size calculation (with CI) for proportions with a 2-arm pre-post design (i.e. experimental and control group)
I've been trying to find how to work out the effect size of an intervention that has only provided information on the proportion of participants who reported they had increased 'knowledge' after the education intervention (experimental) and those who had not (control), compared to baseline. I have looked into relative risk ratio, which seems ideal, but I can't work out confidence interval for the proportion as no CI data is provided in the paper. Any advice would be much appreciated.

The authors really do not give any information about the sample size? If it's a published paper, can you provide its reference? Maybe it contains some information you overlooked or did not know it could be useful to work out confidence intervals.
